# What's the best way to do set-membership tests in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

I'm using hadoop to process a sequence of analytics records for my application.  I want to categorise users based on which events I see in their stream and then use that information in a later stage when iterating over the stream again.  For example, suppose I want to generate data on all the users that never activate my app.

I can work out who never activates by iterating over the stream once as part of my 1st-round reduce.

The question is, where do I put the data that "user X never activated" so that the next time I iterate over the stream in my 2nd-round mapper I can look up that fact?  I have a few ideas but I'm not sure which is the right hadoop way:

- output a side file from my 1st round reducer containing a list of users, read it in in my second-round -- how can I avoid reading the whole file into memory, how do I deal with multiple side files from multiple front-end reducers (is there a good way of sorting/combining side files)?
- buffer all the events of a user in memory in my reducer so that I can tag them all with "not activated" before I output them to disk -- feels a bit icky.

Is one of those "the right way", is there another way that I'm missing?

I'm using AWS Elastic MapReduce.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy with mapreduce.

Mapper: Emit every event as key and your user as value.

e.G:

```
USER_NEVER_ACTIVATED_APP : x
USER_PAID_FOR_APP : x
USER_NEVER_ACTIVATED_APP : y
```

Reducer: You basically get every user for each event.
In this case it would be like this:

```
USER_NEVER_ACTIVATED_APP : x,y
USER_PAID_FOR_APP : x
```

This way you don't even need a second mapper or job.

Comment: Sorry, not sure that answers my question.  I know how to work out which users are activated.  What I want is to "join" that information back onto the event stream for a user so that, when I'm looking at the first event from a user, I have the context that, later, they failed to activate.

It's the join part rather than the generate part that I could do with pointers on.

Comment: So put them into RAM, onto the disk, use HBase or another database.